# How can I float molecules in \chemfig around an element? (without the lines)

Tags: chemfig

For example:

[image]

I just want to show that the H2O molecules are attracted to the Carbon atom. I can't find a way to remove the lines connecting the Oxygens to the Carbons or how to extend the Hydrogens out from the Oxygens.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{C^+(-[:0]O)(-[:90]O)(-[:180]O)(-[:270]O)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you show us a minimal code of your attempts to this figure? For starters, strip out the parts of your code that is not important to drawing this figure and post the resulting [minimal working or non-working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) here.

Comment: I wasn't sure which parts of the code are vital as I just started using LaTeX for the first time today. I just downloaded this template off the internet and it seems to work fine for my math document, but I'm having trouble with this chemistry stuff.

Comment: I have modified your code into an MWE as the template seems to load a lot of stuff that you will not need for now in drawing the figure. I hope the edit was okay. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pure chemfig solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol{eau}{O(-[::-45]H)-[::45]H}
\def\dist{.75}% set the distance between C+ and water
\chemfig{C^{+}(-[:180,\dist,,,draw=none]!{eau})(-[:60,\dist,,,draw=none]!{eau})-[:-60,\dist,,,draw=none]!{eau}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's a "pure" `chemfig` solution, but you could use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to place the molecules at the desired positions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand\Water{\chemfig{O(-[1]H)-[7]H}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
\node (cp) {\chemfig{C^+}};
\node[above right=-20pt and 10pt of cp,rotate around={40:(cp)}] {\Water};
\node[below right=-20pt and 10pt of cp,rotate around={-40:(cp)}] {\Water};
\node[left=40pt of cp,xscale=-1] {\Water};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another option (this time a `TikZ`-free one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\Water{\chemfig{O(-[1]H)-[7]H}}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(100,200)
\put (0,0){\chemfig{C^+}}
\put (10,10) {\rotatebox{40}{\Water}}
\put (10,-10) {\rotatebox{-40}{\Water}}
\put (-45,5) {\scalebox{-1}{\Water}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Is there a way to move the Oxygens closer to the Carbon? I'm playing around with the numbers but I can't seem to make them go closer to the Carbon.

Comment: @latexuser please see my updated answer